# Using generators to read two files in time priority

Tags: python, time, generator

I just read up on generators and was wondering how you would use generators in this:
Say there are two files and each file has a time column. Each file is sorted by ascending time, and I'm looking to grab lines in these files using time priority. Instead of writing an unsophisticated expression(see below) I was wondering if creating a generator next() would be a better/appropriate way to read these two files in time priority.

```
for line1 in file1:    
    do_something
    try:
        if time1<time2:
            do_something    
            continue
        else:
            do_something  
    except:
        pass  
    for line2 in file2:
        do_something  
        if time2>time1:
            break
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [heapq.merge](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

```
def generate_timeline(file):
    for line in file:
         time1 = extract_time_from_line(line)
         yield time1, line


for (time1, line) in heapq.merge(generate_timeline(file1), generate_timeline(file2)):
    process(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and much faster!

Comment: I had one quick follow-up: say before the for-loop I had a while loop that was: while time>time1. And I'd want it to exit the loop if both files ended before this condition was satisfied. How would I get the generator to do this. It doesn't appear to be as simple as putting yield None in the generator.

Comment: @FancyDolphin, `raise GeneratorExit` within the generator

Comment: @FancyDolphin, I might have been a little bit terse there. I meant to say, call `raise GeneratorExit` where you need to exit the generator based on some specific condition

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. I would need to to raise the exit on the while loop before even calling the generator. This would requiring flagging the end of the file for both file1 and file2, which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: @FancyDolphin, set a flag in your while loop when the condition is met. Raise `GeneratorExit` first thing within the generator if flag is `True`. This would cause `heapq.merge` to exit without looping

Comment: heapq.merge is just looping over the two arguments. And the generator is just working on two lines keeping a pointer in the file. What is causing them to loop over the two files is the while loop. The issue is that if the while loop is not satisfied (such as when the file times end before expected) this causes the loop to continue to call the generator and heapq indefinately. I hope that clarifies the problem/my understanding. I'm wondering how to stop this process by hanging, by being able to tell if the pointers on both files have reached the end so that I can exit the while loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30216/discussion-between-fancydolphin-and-ravoori)